Two new circuits, two GFCI outlets, common return and ground, only one GFCI works
I have just wired in two new circuits from my panel into a room where I'd like to have two separate GFCI outlets (each on their own circuit). I used a common return and ground for each GFCI outlet, which I strongly suspect has something to do with the problem. When I power up the new circuits, one GFCI works perfectly, and the other seems to be stuck in a constant state of fault. I have included a simple diagram of the wiring. Why is only one GFCI working? If I use the test button on the working GFCI to fault it, the other GFCI still doesn't work. Thoughts, info and advise from electricians would be much appreciated. Cheers Ash

You should edit your graphic to change your usage of GFIC to GFCI. This is the recognized usage. I edited your message text and the title already.

Can you swap the two GFCI outlets?  That could tell you if there's a wiring problem, versus if one of the GFCIs has the problem.

Resolved! - After double checking all the wiring protocols and reviewing some articles on this situation I was left with one last obvious thing to check. The damn wire nuts in the junction box, located under the house (with very little crawl space.) Sure enough, there was a return white wire on the "bad" GFIC that backed out of the wire nut just enough to break the connection, but wasn't visible when I buttoned up the junction box lid.

@AshVandersteenPersonal -- please post your comment as an answer and I'll +1 it

@crip659 You’re wrong. There is no reason why the setup in the drawing shouldn’t work. Load-side neutrals would need to be separate but there aren’t any so that’s irrelevant.

@RMDman No. The setup presented is perfectly fine.

There's no reason your pictured setup shouldn't work. Possibly one of your new GFCI's is defective, or there is some as yet undiscovered error in your wiring.
